# Why does execution time of the same program differ for two similar CPUs?

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, benchmarking

I am trying to figure out why does program (code below) runs faster using two treads instead of four on Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz but on Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz four thread version runs faster than two thread version of the same program.

```
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <math.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <omp.h>

int main ( void );
void timestamp ( void );

int main ( void )
{
    double a[500][500];
    double angle;
    double b[500][500];
    double c[500][500];
    int i;
    int j;
    int k;
    int n = 500;
    double pi = M_PI;
    double s;
    int thread_num;
    double wtime;

    timestamp ( );

    printf ( "\n" );
    printf ( "MXM_OPENMP:\n" );
    printf ( "  C/OpenMP version\n" );
    printf ( "  Compute matrix product C = A * B.\n" );

    omp_set_dynamic(0);
    omp_set_num_threads(2);  /* Change param to modify number of threads */

    thread_num = omp_get_max_threads ( );

    printf ( "\n" );
    printf ( "  The number of processors available = %d\n", omp_get_num_procs ( ) );
    printf ( "  The number of threads available    = %d\n", thread_num );

    printf ( "  The matrix order N                 = %d\n", n );

    /*Loop 1: Evaluate A.*/

    s = 1.0 / sqrt ( ( double ) ( n ) );

    wtime = omp_get_wtime ( );

    # pragma omp parallel shared ( a, b, c, n, pi, s ) private ( angle, i, j, k )
        {
        # pragma omp for
            for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
            {
                for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                {
                    angle = 2.0 * pi * i * j / ( double ) n;
                    a[i][j] = s * ( sin ( angle ) + cos ( angle ) );
                }
         }

/* Loop 2: Copy A into B.*/

       # pragma omp for
           for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
           {
               for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                   {
                   b[i][j] = a[i][j];
                   }
           }

/* Loop 3: Compute C = A * B.*/

        # pragma omp for
            for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
            {
                for ( j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                {
                    c[i][j] = 0.0;
                    for ( k = 0; k < n; k++ )
                    {
                        c[i][j] = c[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        printf ( "  The number of threads used    = %d\n", omp_get_num_threads() );
    }
    wtime = omp_get_wtime ( ) - wtime;
    printf ( "  Elapsed seconds = %g\n", wtime );
    printf ( "  C(100,100)  = %g\n", c[99][99] );
    /*Terminate.*/
    printf ( "\n" );
    printf ( "MXM_OPENMP:\n" );
    printf ( "  Normal end of execution.\n" );

    printf ( "\n" );
    timestamp ( );
    return 0;
}
void timestamp ( void )
{
# define TIME_SIZE 40
    static char time_buffer[TIME_SIZE];
    const struct tm *tm;
    time_t now;

    now = time ( NULL );
    tm = localtime ( &now );

    strftime ( time_buffer, TIME_SIZE, "%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p", tm );

    printf ( "%s\n", time_buffer );

    return;
# undef TIME_SIZE
}
```

Comment: First line says "2 threads" runs faster; last line says "4 threads" runs faster. So which one? How many processor units you have ?

Comment: Putting more than five megabytes on the stack may be a bad idea.

Comment: Both processors have the same number of physical cores (2) and both support hyperthreading, but there are subtle differences in architecture that may explain the difference you observe. Is this difference significant and systematic?

Comment: The only significant differences between these processors from looking at this comparison page: http://ark.intel.com/compare/81015,67355 seem to be the amount of cache size and the availability of extended instructions.  Not really an explanation.  Maybe the hyperthreading architecture is more efficient on the more modern i7.

Comment: Chqrlie you understood my problem better that others. I was hoping somebody could be able to explain the difference between architectures. And yes difference is significant and systematic. We run both versions of program 30 times on both machines and got consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have the exact same machine all same functionality still execution time may be different. Why?
Because, when may be in Machine 1, 200 services are running and in machine 2, 225 then program in machine 2 will  get less time on processor/resources which may lead to extra time.

It exactly depends on running services (Background and foreground both).

Comment: and you are still using different machines.

Comment: Yes, I'm using different machines but argument of running services is not valid, because I live-booted Ubuntu 15.04 on both of those.